# Distinct Pair sum swift

Tags: swift

Hi am trying to get the number of distinct pair that add up to a particular value. currently I am able to get equal pairs but I am unable to get a work around for distinct pairs.

```
func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> Int {

    for (i, x) in numbers.enumerated() {
        for y in numbers[i+1 ..< numbers.count] {
            if x + y == target {
                return x
            }
            if x + y > target {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return 0
}

print(checkPairs(in: [5,7,9,13,11,6,6,3,3], forSum: 12))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets are great for keeping track of unique things.  Since you want (5, 7) and (7, 5) to be counted as the same pair, you can always store them in the same order (lowest value first, for instance).  Use a struct to store the pair and make it `Hashable` so that it can be used with a `Set`.  Then add your pairs to the `Set` as you find them and get the `.count` at the end.

```
struct Pair: Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int

    var description: String { "(\(x), \(y))" }

    init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
        self.x = min(x, y)
        self.y = max(x, y)
    }
}


func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> Int {

    var set = Set<Pair>()

    for (i, x) in numbers.enumerated() {
        for y in numbers[i+1 ..< numbers.count] {
            if x + y == target {
                set.insert(Pair(x, y))
            }
        }
    }
    print(set)
    return set.count
}

print(checkPairs(in: [5,7,9,13,11,6,6,3,3], forSum: 12))
```

> ```
> [(6, 6), (5, 7), (3, 9)]
> 3
> ```